# System crashes during boot while mounting /lib/init/rw

Tags: filesystems, corruption

After a nasty crash,  my system keeps crashing during boot. After a little bit of investigation I have discovered that it crashes executing the following function (in `/lib/inin/mount_functions`):

```
mount -f -t tmpfs -onosuid,size=5242880,mode=755 tmpfs /lib/init/rw < /dev/null
```

called from `/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh`.

Can anyone suggest what sort of system corruption might cause this problem?

Comment: Do you have any kind of error message/kernel panic? (I'm assuming this is some kind of Linux you have?)

Comment: Is there anything in the kernel logs (usually `/var/log/kern.log`)? Have you performed a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/) recently?

Comment: Can you run fsck -p against your existing filesystems before it crashes?  And, is this in initrd, or is your root filesystem mounted by this point?

Answer (score 0):

It this happens *before* it switches to the real root (i.e., in the `initramfs` still), you can try booting an older kernel and reinstall the oldest one (to fix the broken `instramfs`).

If not the above, probably your best bet is to get rescue media (on Fedora, RHEL and clones it is intergrated in the installation DVD, and I thin also in the minimal install isos; I presume other distributions are similar), and `fsck(8)` your filesystems. Start in runlevel 1 later (add '1' to the kernel line) and take it from there.